# Missing dot (.) in email address - getProfileUserInfo() on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I use [`identity.getProfileUserInfo()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo) to get currently logged-in user's e-mail address.  However, on Chrome OS (Beta, channel 44) a dot (.) - if present - is removed from the address.

For example, if address is `first.last@domain.com` the returned address is `firstlast@domain.com`

The same API returns correct/full address in Chrome on Windows.

Has anyone run into this problem? Any workarounds?

Comment: While it's probably a valid bug, can you explain why this matters? Those addresses are synonymous for most intents and purposes. Also, have you tried logging out and logging back in expressly with the `.` present?

Comment: And you should be using `userId` to correlate users not email so the `userId` will be the same on all platforms.

Comment: The e-mail address is used in another place for confirmation purposes.  It is also displayed so a corresponding user can verify it.  The address is not being used for authentication.

Comment: ... continuing    For example, we let end users know what addresses they used for certain actions.  It just does not look right if our software claims that a given user's address is 'lastfirst@domain.com' - because this is what we get from GetProfileUserInfo - while Chrome browser on on the same Chrome OS displays it properly (i.e. 'last.first@domain.com').

Comment: You should file a bug regarding this at https://crbug.com/new You should probably mention [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=430290) in the new one as I believe this is where it originates. I'd prefer not to make a bug myself since I don't have access to Chrome OS for relevant details - but please post the issue link here when you create it.

Comment: Filed as a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513697

Answer (score 1):

**Consumer** Gmail [ignores dots/periods](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313) in the username, Gmail for **Google Apps** [does not](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en), i.e. for consumer Gmail addresses `username@gmail.com`, `user.name@gmail.com` and even `u.s.e.r.n...a.m.e@gmail.com` are all the same.

I don't know of another email a service that does this, and all other services I know consider "dotted" Gmail addresses distinct from their "undotted" variant.

`getProfileUserInfo()` either normalizes the email address by stripping periods or the account is logged in to Chrome OS with a dotted variant of the email address.